# Google sheets IMPORTXML Return no Data N/A

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to parse such [XML](https://ted.europa.eu/udl?uri=TED:NOTICE:641339-2021:XML:DE:HTML) File using Google sheets Importxml function

```
=IMPORTXML("https://ted.europa.eu/udl?uri=TED:NOTICE:641339-2021:XML:DE:HTML"; "/TED_EXPORT/TECHNICAL_SECTION/RECEPTION_ID")
```

**Returns Error: No Data - N/A**

According to this [tool](https://www.easycodeforall.com/generate-xpath.html) its a valid XPATH and contains data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the site use a namespace, you have to use local-name

```
=importxml(url,"//*[local-name() ='RECEPTION_ID']")
```

[image]

### reference

[local-name() on mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name)

Comment: Hi @MikeSteelson, 
thank you for your reply. Now I stumbled over another related problem which I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70607503/google-sheets-importxml-query-get-attribute-with-local-name

Comment: ok, Tanaike has already answered!