# Google sheets IMPORTXML Query get attribute with local-name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is a follow up question to this previous question: [Google sheets IMPORTXML Return no Data N/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70550364/google-sheets-importxml-return-no-data-n-a)

Given the following [XML](https://ted.europa.eu/udl?uri=TED:NOTICE:641339-2021:XML:DE:HTML) (has namespace) I want to query the `CODE` number inside `CPV_CODE`.

```
<CPV_CODE CODE="90524400"/>
```

With XPATH I would simply use: `/CPV_CODE/@CODE` but as I have to use local-name (due to namespace) I have no idea how to get it.

I tried

```
=importxml(url,"//*[local-name() ='CPV_CODE']")
```

but it does not return the `@CODE` number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following xpath?

#### Sample xpath:

```
//*[local-name()='CPV_MAIN']/*[local-name()='CPV_CODE']/@CODE
```

Or

```
//*[local-name()='CPV_MAIN']//@CODE
```

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[local-name()='CPV_MAIN']/*[local-name()='CPV_CODE']/@CODE")
```

Or

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[local-name()='CPV_MAIN']//@CODE")
```

- In this case, the URL is put in the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- In the URL, it seems that there are 2 `CPV_CODE` tags. If you want to retrieve `<CPV_CODE CODE="90524200"/>`, how about the following formula?

  ```
    =IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[local-name()='CPV_ADDITIONAL']/*[local-name()='CPV_CODE']/@CODE")
  ```

  Or

  ```
    =IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[local-name()='CPV_ADDITIONAL']//@CODE")
  ```

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)